# Finding all Well-Ordered Numbers within a range, how to print last value before while loop stops in C and print only 10 values per line?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf

The objective of the C-program is to print out all the well-ordered numbers between 100 and 999. Well-ordered numbers are numbers that have digits that are at least smaller by 1 when compared to the digit on it's right (e.g. 123, 456, and 159 are all well-ordered numbers).

I start off setting three `integer` values `x`, `y`, and `z` values at `1`, `2`, and `3` respectively as that is the lowest well-ordered number possible in this range. My idea is to increment `z` first so that we get: `123, 124, 125, .. 129`, then whenever it reaches 9 it increments `y` by 1 and `z` is set back down to `y+1` and it follows from there: 134, 135, 136..139 etc. The `while loop` checks if the number has reached the last one in the range between `100` and `999` which is `789`. My so far "working" code is pasted below.

So far the logic works to print out every well-ordered number between `100-999`, but it can't print the last one which is `789` and stops printing at `689` before `x` is incremented one last time. I spent so long trying to figure it out but can't seem to find where to place this print or where the logic can be changed in order to access this final print where `x` is incremented once more so that `789` shows in the answer.

Also the problem I'm working on mentions to print only 10 numbers before returning, and I also couldn't find a way to do this. I'm quite new to the C language so I was wondering if anyone can figure this out and give me some hints or guidance? Have I completely gone about this the wrong way and there is a simpler way to do this?

Thank you all for helping in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x, y, z; 
    x = 1; 
    y = 2; 
    z = 3; 

    while(x != 7 || y != 8 || z != 9) {
        printf("%d%d%d \n", x, y, z); // print well-ordered number

        if(y==8) {
            x++; // only increment x when y is reached the last position
            y = x+1; // put y in the next correct position
            z = y; // put z in the next correct position 
        }
        if(z==9) {
            y++; // only increment y when z's reached the last position
            z = y; // reset z's position
        }

        z++; // increment z as it's always the first priority to maintain a well-ordered number

    }


    return 0; 


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking for != , go for <= .

Rest everything is fine.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem, I really was overlooking that and trying to look and change parts of the code I didn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, if the particular algorithm isn't important, try brute-force.

Just count through all the numbers in the range of interest, and analyze each for being well-ordered or not.

This moves the complexity from "how to increment a number held in three variables while thinking about well-orderedness" to "how to check if a number if well-ordered".

Performance-wise, you won't notice the difference.

Something like this:

```
bool is_well_ordered(int x)
{
  const int hundreds = x / 100;
  const int tens = (x % 100) / 10;
  const int ones = x % 10;

  return x >= 100 && hundreds < tens && tens < ones;
}
```

Then just run that in a loop, printing the number whenever it returns `true`.

When I did that, it printed 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 134 135 136 137 138 139 145 146 147 148 149 156 157 158 159 167 168 169 178 179 189 234 235 236 237 238 239 245 246 247 248 249 256 257 258 259 267 268 269 278 279 289 345 346 347 348 349 356 357 358 359 367 368 369 378 379 389 456 457 458 459 467 468 469 478 479 489 567 568 569 578 579 589 678 679 689 789.

This solution is going to be much much clearer and easier to understand.

Comment: I like your version of the solution very much, thank you. Would you happen to know the second part of my problem in how to print ten results per line before returning?

Comment: @Darkphoton Add a counter for how many numbers you've printed, and when the counter reaches 10 print a newline (`'\n'`). Obvious but true. :)